# Microsoft Chart Controls - Line Series Aliasing

Tags: c#, microsoft-chart-controls

I am using the Microsoft Chart Controls `Chart` class in `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` and have a problem with a line series looking very jagged.

I am setting up my chart like so:

```
    chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
    chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High;
    chart.BackColor = Color.White;
```

And my series is a basic `SeriesChartType.Line` type. I am rendering as a PNG (have also tried BMP and JPG), but the end result it still like the below. I have also tried increasing the line width, but this just makes it more obvious. Is it possible to smooth out the line?

[image: No axis scale]
[image: With axis scale]

Comment: I am plotting about 40 points if that makes a difference.

Comment: It doesn't look like the image is getting rescaled.  So this is normal, an inevitable consequence of monitors having a very low resolution.  A "retina" monitor is nice, you of course can't make that buying decision.  Using a different chart type like a Column graph is an obvious workaround.